# Как вывести ответ в виде целого выражения со всеми знаками?

Tags: java

Сама задача:

> По данному натуральному n≥2 вычислите сумму 1×2+2×3+...+(n-1)×n. Ответ выведите в виде вычисленного выражение и его значения в точности, как показано в примере.

Ввод
4
Вывод
1x2+2x3+3x4=20

Мой код:

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter");
int n = scn.nextInt();
System.out.println("Result");
int sum = 0;
int res = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    res = i * 2;
    sum = sum + res;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас еще ошибка в цикле.

```
   public class Test {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter");
            int n = scn.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Result");
            int sum = 0;
            int res;
            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
                res = i * (i+1);
                System.out.print(i + "*" + (i+1));
                if (i+1 != n) {
                    System.out.print(" + ");
                }
                sum = sum + res;
            }
            System.out.println(" = "+sum);
        }
}
```